# Small matrix spacing and sizing

Tags: matrices

I'm using the small matrix environment to define these 2x1 column vectors like so:

```
setting $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
\beta_x \\
\beta_y
\end{smallmatrix}\right) = \left(\begin{smallmatrix}
0.01 \\
0
\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ results in a ...
```

[image]

However I want the two to have the same height and bracket thickness, although I know having the width equal won't look good. Are there any solutions or alternatives to this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Use `\bigl` and `\bigr` instead of `\left` and `\right`, you can increase the size by using the tags `\Bigl, \biggl, \Biggl`...

Comment: Add `\mathstrut` in the first row of the second matrix.`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't auto-size the parentheses; instead, I'd apply `\bigl` and `\bigr` to both `smallmatrix` environments. If you insist on auto-sizing, I'd go with the `psmallmatrix` environment (provided by the `mathtools` package) and save myself some keystrokes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
setting 
$\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
\beta_x \\ \beta_y
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr) = 
\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
0.01 \\ 0
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ 
results in a \dots

\medskip
setting 
$\begin{psmallmatrix}
\beta_x \\ \beta_y
\end{psmallmatrix} = 
\begin{psmallmatrix}
0.01 \\ 0
\end{psmallmatrix}$ 
results in a \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you this works very well! (going with \bigl \bigr)

Answer (score 4):

You can load `mathtools` and use the simple syntax:

```
setting $\begin{psmallmatrix}
\beta_x \\
\beta_y
\end{psmallmatrix} = \begin{psmallmatrix}
0.01\mathstrut \\
0
\end{psmallmatrix}$ results in a ...
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution looks good here but when I use it in my actual file:

`For instance, setting $\bm{\beta} = \begin{psmallmatrix}
\beta_x \\
\beta_y
\end{psmallmatrix} = \begin{psmallmatrix}
0.01\mathstrut \\
0
\end{psmallmatrix}$ results in a...`

They don't actually match (and yes I did import mathtools)

Comment: There must be something else, because I have no problem adding `\bm{\beta}`. Could you post a minimal, yet complete, code, reproducing the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Use a `\vphantom`.

And as MadyYuvi correctly suggests, additional control can be gained at limiting the vertical height of the parens by replacing the `\left...\right` nomenclature with `\bigl...\bigr`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
setting $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
\beta_x \\
\beta_y
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr) = \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
0.01\vphantom{\beta_x} \\
0\vphantom{\beta_y}
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ results in a ...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A little possible alternative....using  `\tbinom{}{}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
There are  possible little matrix, inlinemath $\tbinom{\beta_x}{\beta_y}=\tbinom{0.01}{0}$
and in displaymath you have the same result
\[\tbinom{\beta_x}{\beta_y}=\tbinom{0.01}{0}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]